# Ant build does not copy xml files

Tags: java, ant

I want to copy my hibernate configuration xml files into a jar which belonging POJO s are built into. Following is my ant build.xml file(I got this from [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheAnt/article.html))

```
  <project name="Ant-Test" default="main" basedir=".">
  <!-- Sets variables which can later be used. -->
  <!-- The value of a property is accessed via ${} -->
  <property name="src.dir" location="src"/>
  <property name="build.dir" location="bin"/>
  <property name="dist.dir" location="dist"/>
  <property name="docs.dir" location="docs"/>
  <!-- Deletes the existing build, docs and dist directory-->
  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <delete dir="${docs.dir}"/>
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}"/>
  </target>
  <!-- Creates the  build, docs and dist directory-->
  <target name="makedir">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${docs.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}"/>
  </target>
  <!-- Compiles the java code (including the usage of library for JUnit -->
  <target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir">
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}">
      <classpath>
        <pathelement path="/jars/log4j.jar"/>
      </classpath>
    </javac>
  </target>
  <!-- copy hbm files ${dist.dir} -->
    <target name="copy-hbm" depends="compile" description="Copy hibernate files">
        <copy todir="${build.dir}" >
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="*.xml" />
        </copy>
    </target>
  <!-- hbm copy over -->
  <!-- Creates Javadoc -->
  <target name="docs" depends="compile">
    <javadoc packagenames="src" sourcepath="${src.dir}" destdir="${docs.dir}">
      <!-- Define which files / directory should get included, we include all -->
      <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
        <include name="**"/>
      </fileset>
    </javadoc>
  </target>
  <!--Creates the deployable jar file  -->
  <target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}\my-hibernate-pojo.jar" basedir="${build.dir}">
      <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="test.Main"/>
      </manifest>
    </jar>
  </target>
  <target name="main" depends="copy-hbm, jar">
    <description>Main target</description>
  </target>
</project>
```

This generates the jar file but hibernate configuration xml s are not copied into the jar. Any one let me know where the problem can exists

Comment: Which target are you running?

Comment: Where are the xml files stored?  Your `<copy-hbm>` target copies them from `bin` to `dist`, but `bin` is emptied by the `<clean>` target, so I can't tell how the xml files get put into `bin`.

Comment: Your "jar" target create jar from "${build.dir}".  Your copy-hbm should copy the hbm files from its sources to {build.dir}.  Please test individual targets before debugging the main. Also, the jar target (in your case) must depend on "copy-hbm".

Comment: Use ant -debug to see some helpful(but very verbose) messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I thank all who answered my question.
I found the issue which is wrong including xml file name params. Here I post the solution which I found as this may help some one else.

I made the copy-hbm target modified as following it worked.

```
<copy todir="${build.dir}" >
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.xml" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
```

The change I made was,  **includes="*.xml"** was replaced with name="**/*.xml". Wrong was with the path definition.  some credits should be offered to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109564/ant-excluding-files) question as I picked up his way of setting the include class path

Comment: It's probably better to specify ```<exclude name="**/*.java" />``` so that you can pick up property files etc.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make it work by changing your `copy-hbm` target to the following:

```
<target name="copy-hbm" depends="compile" description="Copy hibernate files">
    <copy todir="${build.dir}" >
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="*.xml" />
    </copy>
</target>
```

The only change is the `dir` should be `src` and `todir` should be `bin`.

This worked for me. Hope it works for you too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the code, but it didn't work for me. I use the Ant 1.7. Does it matter this ?

Comment: Oh! That's strange.. I was able to make it work with exactly this change.. I even re-tested it by taking your XML again and pasting this snippet and rerunning ant. For what it's worth, I have ant 1.9.4. And I really don't think that should matter...

Comment: Your script is not copying the XML file from the SRC folder to the bin folder and that's why it is not being bundled into the jar. When you tested using my snippet, did you take the XML from this post and then place my snippet over yours? Or did you use a different one on your computer?

Comment: Thanks anacron for your support. I updated the build xml in my answer which I exactly run. the copy-hbm target also replaced with what you mentioned.. Stil not working.. :(

Comment: The updated full build xml in your question worked for me. But then, I looked at your answer and understood what your problem was. I thought that the hibernate xml file was directly under the src folder. That was how it was working for me. Good that you were able to solve it and I appreciate that you posted back the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. change the dependencies on `main` to include `copy-hbm` instead of
   `compile` so that your copy runs
2. Change either the copy task or the jar task to have the same destination/source.   You're currently copy the xml files to build.dir and then jarring up dest.dir

Comment: Thankks thekbb. But, changes were made but still xmls are not copied. The build xml was modified and updated in the question.

Comment: the question still has the basedir of the jar task as the `build.dir`... that won't get the xml files you've copied to `dist.dir`.  change your `copy-hbm `task to have the `todir=${build.dir}`

Comment: I appreciate your support. Still I couldn't solve this even after the xml is changed as you advised.I updated the xml in my question.

Comment: Also I found that, the bin directory  has no xml files. I manually copied xml files into the bin and ran the ant build.xml file. Then the jar had included those xml files as I expected. As the problem is seen, the bin directory doesn't consist of xml files to be copied into the jar. Then I tried to set the source as src of xml copy target, then those xml files were not included in the jar.